# I am trying to create user registration form in js which beautiful and flexible

Tags: users, javascript

I am using drupal 7. I am trying to create user registration form with javascript which beautiful and flexible. Something like this:

[image]

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it by using these modules :

[Fancy Login](https://www.drupal.org/project/fancy_login)

> Fancy Login adds javascript based, lightbox-style login functionality
>   to your site. When the user clicks on any link that links to
>   /user/login, they screen dims and a login box is created in the center
>   of the screen.

[Better Login](https://www.drupal.org/project/betterlogin)

> Styling Drupal login/password/registration forms are a mission most of
>   the time because they form part of the theme... This module removes
>   that issue, it is slightly inspired by the way Wordpress login forms
>   work, and uses three page templates to change the style of the forms.
>   It is very simple to use, just install the Better Login module and it
>   starts working immediately.

[Model Form](https://www.drupal.org/project/modal_forms)

> Modal forms make use of the modal feature in the ctools module to open
>   some common forms in a modal window.

Answer (score 2):

Call User Login block in colorbox. Use colorbox module.
For Forgot Password and Need and Account? Sign Up Link You can use form_alter i.e. Drupal Form API

If you totally want to do it with JS then also you can use colorbox library.

```
jQuery("#id-of-link-which-on-click-will-open-colorbox").colorbox({
   inline:true,
   href:'#id-of-block-to-open-in-colorbox',
   width:"1000px",
   height:"600px",
   transition:"fade",
   scrolling: false 
});
```

For Forgot Password and Sign Up Link You can use append / prepend HTML accordingly.